# Blowfish Cipher - bitwise XORing the secret key with the P array

Tags: python, python-3.x, blowfish

I'm trying to implement the [Blowfish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_%28cipher%29#The_algorithm) algorithm in Python.  I think I have a decent general understanding of the algorithm but some of the implementation details are losing me.

The algorithm involves an array of hexadecimals

```
#Note: I shortened the 18 element array for this example
PI_P_ARRAY = (0x243f6a88, 0x85a308d3, 0x13198a2e, 0x03707344)
```

and a secret key

```
key = 'mysecret'
```

From Wikipedia, "The secret key is, byte by byte, cycling the key if necessary, XORed with all the P-entries in order."  How do I implement this in Python?

So far, I can't even convert the key to hex!  Much less cycle it into a hex array that I can XOR with the P-array...

```
#Failed attempts to convert key to hex

import binascii
binascii.hexlify(key)

key.encode('hex')

bytearray(key)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `PI_P_ARRAY` array is just an array of integers using hex literals, so I don't think you need to mess about with hex for this. Instead, convert your key into a sequence of integers. The simplest way is to use a `bytearray` like `bytearray(key, "utf-8")`. Then, you can either zip the lists like so:

```
zip(itertools.cycle(PI_P_ARRAY), bytearray(key, "utf-8"))
```

The `itertools.cycle` will repeat the `PI_P_ARRAY` for the whole length of the `key`. You can then make a list comprehension to give you the XORed values like so:

```
[p ^ k for p, k in zip(itertools.cycle(PI_P_ARRAY), bytearray(key, "utf-8"))]
```

This gives you a `list` of `int`s. Or, using a map:

```
map(operator.xor, itertools.cycle(PI_P_ARRAY), bytearray("secret", "utf-8"))
```

Note that this gives you a generator, which will use less memory if you are handling large amounts of data.